# Livewire - Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on string

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I get a error from livewire file uploading "Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on string" Please help me any why I get the problem from livewire controller functions. I attached livewire form and controller function codes.

```html
<div class="mb-3 col-xl-8">
  <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
          <form wire:submit.prevent="RegisterNewUserAdmin">
              <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-lg-1">
                      <select class="form-control" wire:model.prevent="RegisterUserMethods">
                          <option value="" selected>Select</option>
                          <option value="manually">Manually</option>
                          <option value="fromXLSfile">From XLS File</option>  
                      </select>
                  </div>                               
                      <div class="col-lg-3">
                          <input type="text" wire:model="newusername" class="form-control" placeholder="Write User Full Name" required>
                      </div>                                    
                      <div class="col-lg-3">
                          <input type="email" wire:model="newuseremail" class="form-control" placeholder="Write Email ID" required>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-lg-3">
                          <input type="password" wire:model="newuserpassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-lg-9">
                          <input type="file" wire:model="NewUserxlsFile" class="form-control" required>
                      </div>                                   
                  <div class="col-lg-2">
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success w-100"><div wire:loading wire:target="RegisterNewUserAdmin" class="spinner-border"></div> Add Now</button>
                  </div>                                                     
              </div>
          </form>
      </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Controller Function

```
public function RegisterNewUserAdmin()
{
    $str = Str::random(10);
    $file = $this->NewUserxlsFile;
    $filename = $str.'.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension();

    $path = $this->NewUserxlsFile->storeAs('files/xls/', $filename, 'public');
    $data = Excel::load($path)->get();
    dd($data);
}
```

Comment: can you please upload the whole controller class. not just the function

Comment: Sounds like it has something to do with your `NewUserxlsFile` variable. How is it defined in your component?

Comment: Have you added the `WithFileUploads` trait to your class? What does the rest of your component look like?